# c# DeSerialize NaN values into JSON in using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

Tags: nan, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I need to convert NaN in Json(as it is not JSON) to Double using System.Text.Json

For example, I am having following JSON:

```json
{ "Amount": NaN }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please also check this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40140)

Comment: You are correct, `{ "Amount": NaN }` is actually malformed JSON.  System.Text.Json rejects such malformed JSON even with `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/pRPC8x.  And `Utf8JsonReader` is sealed so there's no possibility to change its behavior.  Json.NET, however, does have a special case for such malformed JSON, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/qzYpjj.  You may need to stick with Json.NET to handle this unusual case.  Or get the sending system to fix their JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To serialized/deserialized, You can use an alternative way (such as strings)
Json.NET stores these as strings in the payload then automatically converts to float. To demonstrate you can check the following code:

```cs
public class ClassWithNumbers
{
    public int IntNumber { get; set; }
    public float FloatNumber { get; set; }
}

// Json Serialization Options to allow literals 
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals
};

// Json Exmple
string json = @"{""IntNumber"":1,""FloatNumber"":""NaN""}";
ClassWithNumbers obj =     System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClassWithNumbers>(json, options);

Output:
// obj.IntNumber: 1
// obj.FloatNumber: NaN
```

Comment: This will work for `{ "Amount": "NaN" }` but querent needs to deserialize `{ "Amount": NaN }` (without quotes around the NaN).  They correctly identify that this is not well-formed JSON, but seem to need to deserialize it anyway.  Json.NET does support unquoted NaN values for doubles despite it being malformed, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/qzYpjj.