# Interoperability of Infinity, -Infinity and NaN in JSON ecosystem?

Tags: json, interop, ieee-754

I am trying to understand if there is some sort of portability of `Infinity, -Infinity, NaN` in the JSON world ([StringNumericLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#prod-StringNumericLiteral)). I understand that `Infinity, -Infinity, NaN` are not specified in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), I am just trying to find a common ground in between different languages.

In the end it should be be compatible with JavaScript.

Comment: In C# the widely used Json.NET library supports both styles, see [FloatFormatHandling Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatFormatHandling.htm).

Comment: Incidentally `JsonNode` can **parse** quoted named number literals like `"Infinity"`, it just won't automatically recognize them as doubles.  But you can subsequently deserialize one to a `double` and it will work, e.g. `d = JsonNode.Parse("\"Infinity\"").Deserialize<double>(new JsonSerializerOptions { NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals });` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/7FHCHN.

Comment: The link you provided to the ECMAScript specification has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: It's not my question which is confusing. It's the fact the M$ implemented `AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals` for string based only. In any case ECMAScript is the number one consumer of JSON, so interoperability needs to consider this particular specification.

Comment: What is the question? The problem with encoding NaN as "NaN" is that (1) now you cannot encode the string "NaN" anymore, (2) the consumer must be aware of this deviation from JSON. The problem with encoding NaN as a NaN token (violating JSON), is that clients will often trip over such syntax violations, like `JSON.parse` in ECMAScript will throw.

Comment: In the overview table, you indicate that NodeJs supports the suggested extension without quotes, but that is not true. `JSON.parse('NaN')`  throws. Only with quotes it doesn't throw: `JSON.parse('"NaN"')`, but then its value is not NaN. You seem to suggest that `Number` is a JSON parser, but it is not. Also, when adding the (literal) quotes, `Number` will *always* evaluate the input as NaN. For instance: `Number('"1"')` is still NaN. Not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some experiment (F12 in google chrome), I see that the extension for those special `Number` value are like:

```js
> Number("-Infinity")
-Infinity
```

while:

```js
> Number("-Inf")
NaN
```

I see two candidates for some kind of interoperabilty:

1. `[NaN, Infinity, -Infinity]` or
2. `["NaN", "Infinity", "-Infinity"]`

Now if I need to process this JSON file among different languages/framework. Here is what I am observing today (the goal is that the JSON produced does not trigger exception when processed):

| Language | No quotes | With quotes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node.js | ❌ [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228651/how-to-parse-json-string-containing-nan-in-node-js) | ✅ supported, thanks to [number coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion) |
| python3 | ✅ [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601812/sending-nan-in-json) ([allow_nan=True](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)) | ❌ not supported |
| [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer) | ❌ not supported | ✅ [supported (AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71289939/c-sharp-deserialize-nan-values-into-json-in-using-system-text-json-serialization) |
| [System.Text.Json.JsonNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode) | ❌ [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454679/jsonnode-how-to-parse-nan-infinity-infinity) | ❌ not supported |
| Json.NET | ✅ [supported](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatFormatHandling.htm) | ✅ supported (contrib from user dbc) |

We could add some more I suspect. But the conclusion is that JSON extensions for NaN, Infinity, -Infinity are incompatibles based on the framework used.

So as of today, the only portable way to carry out those special values are as string representation with exactly those values:

```json
["NaN", "Infinity", "-Infinity"]
```

`"NaN"` would be a special string and would need special care, since any non valid string returns `NaN` in ECMAScript anyway.

Comment: Referring to `Number` in ECMAScript does not seem relevant. That function cannot parse JSON, nor is it intended for that. You say that *"any non valid string returns `NaN` in ECMAScript"*, (when I think you refer to the `Number` function), but it is more than that: it will also return `NaN` for some *valid* JSON. For instance, `Number("false")` is not `false`, but `NaN`. I really think you are mixing up things here, and should concentrate on `JSON.parse` and not `Number` when looking at ECMAScript.